# Use of "auto" causes deadlysignal, but "auto&" works fine with operator[] of map

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, auto, return-by-reference

I have created a adjacency list using

`map<string,priority_queue<string, vector<string>, greater<string>>>& adjList`

now when  I try to access a value using below method

`auto dest = adjList[start];`

i get runtime error : "AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL"

And if i use

`auto& dest = adjList[start];`

it works fine and no runtime error.

Please help me understand what is difference.

complete code below

```
void dfs(string start, map<string,priority_queue<string, vector<string>, greater<string>>>& trips, vector<string>& res)
    {
        auto dest = trips[start];
        while(!dest.empty())
        {
            auto s = dest.top();
            dest.pop();
            dfs(s,trips,res);
        }
        res.push_back(start);
    }


    vector<string> findItinerary(vector<vector<string>>& tickets) {
        vector<string> result;
        map<string,priority_queue<string, vector<string>, greater<string>>> adjList;
        for(auto i : tickets)
        {
            auto it = adjList.find(i[0]);
            if(it == adjList.end())
            {
                adjList[i[0]] = priority_queue<string, vector<string>, greater<string>>();
            }
            adjList[i[0]].push(i[1]);
        }
        vector<string> res;
        dfs("JFK",adjList,res);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: `auto` uses the template rules for type deduction, so it will never deduce "reference". If you want a reference you must say so with `auto&`.

Comment: `auto` and `auto&` there do fundamentally different things.  One creates a copy, the other gets a reference, to what is in the map.  You mutate the `dest`; when it is a reference, this mutates what is in the map.  When it isn't a reference, it mutates a copy (which is discarded shortly afterwards).  The fact that these two programs behave differently is completely unsurprising.  What exactly your code is intending to so is difficult without you saying what it is intended to do.

Comment: Can you post the *whole* code, including your `main` function where you create the `trips` map and call `dfs` or `findItinerary` ?